# Can't save a instance using NHibernate

Tags: c#, exception, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm experiencing a problem, when I try to save a instance using NHibernate on a WPF +  C# application.

Debugging it, show that the errors occurs on step `session.Save(MyInstance);`
You can see the complete method below. The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
>   Additional information: could not insert: [Blog.Models.Province][SQL:
>   INSERT INTO [Province] (CodProv, NomeProv, Regiao) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
>   select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

```
private void txt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using(ISession session = NHibernateHelper.AbreSession())           
    {
        Province province = new Province();

            province.CodProv = "11";
            province.NomeProv = "Maputo Cidade";
            province.Regiao = "Sul";                

        ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        session.Save(province);
        tx.Commit();
    }
```

The NHibernateHelper Class

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory factory = CriaSessionFactory();

    private static ISessionFactory CriaSessionFactory()
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure(cfg)
           .Mappings(x =>
           {
               x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(
                   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
           }).BuildSessionFactory();

        return factory;
    }

    public static ISession AbreSession()
    {
        return factory.OpenSession();
    }      
}
```

Someone can help me?

Here's my Province and Mapping classes

```
public class Province
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string CodProv { get; set; }
    public virtual string NomeProv { get; set; }
    public virtual string Regiao { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping class

```
public class ProvinceMapping : ClassMap<Province>
{
     public ProvinceMapping()
     {
          Id(province => province.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
          Map(province => province.CodProv);
          Map(province => province.NomeProv);
          Map(province => province.Regiao);              
     }            
}
```

If necessary, here's my table province script.

```
    CREATE TABLE Provincia(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
codProv  VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
nomeProv VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
regiao   VARCHAR(10) );
```

Comment: You should show your mapping, but in this case it would be almost for sure "missing IDENTITY" on the DB colun Province_ID... And also, important: **observe the rest of the exception... the next line will for sure contain the clear answer**

Comment: @RadimKöhler Apparenty he is using automatic mappings. @ Elmodai, because the mapping is implicit, could you also add the code for the `Province` class?

Comment: @MauriceStam it is not about mapping. I would bet that the DB column "Province_ID" - table "Province" is expected to be IDENTITY... but I would say it is not. Anyhow, exactly that answer is in the exception... just next line ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler Yes you are correct. We'll have to await the exception details.

Comment: @RadimKöhler, I just added the details (Province class) you asked. Added Mapping class to, and even the SQL Script that create the table.

Comment: @elmodai, great job, could you please also post the complete stack trace? that will help us immediately to see what is the issue... In my Answer, I tried to show you the inner exception... there will be the clear problem description... what disallows the INSERT statement...

Comment: @elmodai I checked your updated question, and would say that if you copy pasted your real stuff... the answer is clear. Check my answer Province vs Provincia

Comment: @RadimKöhler I just change thetable name from Provincia to Province in order to create a consistence. But even so, the errors still persiste. Check the stack trace a added

Comment: Please, do not place the exception trace into my answer, but to your question. And the part you pasted into my answer in fact again does not contain the inner exception... there will be the answer

Comment: Oh, sorry @RadimKöhler. I not a frequently user in SOF (Stack Over Flow), so I'm not familiarized...
I just post the stack trace you ask. You can see at the end of stack, indicating --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
I can't post over 30000 characters. :(

Comment: It seems that the issue is not with DB. Because, I deleted the table Province, and the error is the same!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my config:
I have 2 connectionString
1.With name Blog2 -> that I use to connect the Local DB (mdf)
2. Name Blog - > I use to connect SQL Server DB (dbo)

NHibernate only works connected to a local DB!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"
              type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>

    <startup>     
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

  <connectionStrings>  

    <add name="blog2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Elmodai\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Blog\Blog\DB1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>

    <add name="blog" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=ELMODAI-PC;Initial Catalog=VamosVer;Integrated Security=True"/>

  </connectionStrings>

  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>

      <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect
      </property>

      <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
      </property>

      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">
        blog
      </property>

      <property name="show_sql">
        ture
      </property>

      <property name="format_sql">
        ture
      </property>

      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">
        update
      </property>

    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

BASED ON THE MAPPING

Related to updated question, there is one inconsistence in the mapping, check the:

- `[SQL: INSERT INTO` **`[Province]`** `(`
- `CREATE TABLE` **`Provincia`** `(`

So, if there is no typo in the question, the problem is clear, There is no table *Province*... just **Provincia**

ORIGINAL PART

NHibernate exceptions are the real treasure, because there are **all the secrets described in detail**. Your exceptions, the full stack trace, most likely looks like this:

```
// YOUR part
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll Additional information: could not insert: [Blog.Models.Province][SQL: INSERT INTO [Province] (CodProv, NomeProv, Regiao) VALUES (?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

```
// next part - inner exception
```

> ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Province_ID', table 'Province'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

It could be even another inner exception, but from its description you will clearly now.

In case, that the issue is **`"column does not allow nulls"`** it means, that we expect:

```
Id(x => x.Id, "Province_ID")
   .GeneratedBy.Identity()
   ...
```

while DB is **not** set as:

```
[Province_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

Just be sure that your ID column has the IDENTITY defined, ALTER it to have it...

Comment: I tried to assist ASAP... really not sure what is happening on your side... but there is last try - change your driver from SqlClientDriver to Sql2008ClientDriver.

Comment: Koler,
I Just solve the problem. I need to create the table manually on SQL Server, and then, Insert data using Hibernate.

Comment: So we do have solution ;) great to see that;) Enjoy NHibernate